# Calculate of amount column in DATAGRID VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

let say i have following datagrid as follow :

Column 1------------Column 2

1-----------------------true

2-----------------------False

3-----------------------False

4-----------------------False

5-----------------------True

if i want to show total of "True" in "Column 2" into textbox.text, how to do that that?

need kind help,

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Web or Winform? `DataGridView` is Winform control, `DataGrid` - Web (ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function CountTrueRows() As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If DataGridView1.Item("Column2", i).Value = True Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

Comment: if you are using datagridview in windows form